# Cascade of N-MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, bms

I want to control multiple battery banks w.r.t. charging and discharging. Each bank has a HX-3S-F100A Battery Management System which controls the low side (charging with 5 parallel N-MOSFETs so as discharging).

I can't (and want to) modify the BMS. In order to control charging of the bank from a power bus or discharging to the load, I placed some N-MOSFETs between the BMS and the power bus (MP1) and to load discharging (MP3) low side.

The discharging low side line works perfect with full current when on and zero current when off.
My problem is the charging side. The N-MOSFET do not close fully. Still 1/6 of current flows.

What did I do wrong in the design?

[image]

Comment: did you forget the body diode?

Comment: Which body diode? I assumed the choosen MOSFETs have a build in diode.

Comment: You should have resistors in the gate of each MOSFET, maybe 50 Ohm. The "Body" diode is not built in or added it is inherent in the process. Here is a link to the data sheet.

Comment: This schematic is hard to read, use ports to make it more readable. Describe the potentials on MP1, MP2, MP3 and what they are connected to.

Comment: MP1 is a terminal to the charging source's GND, MP3 is a terminal to the load's GND, MP2 is a common terminal to the charging source's 12.6V high potential and to the load's high potential, it is directly connected to the batteries.

Comment: Added the 1k resistors to the LU024 MOSFET but no change in behaviour.